# ShellExecuteEx lpVerb of "openas" but Once (dont change default)

Tags: winapi

I'm using `ShellExecuteEx` to open a path with the "Open With" dialog of Windows.

I do this by setting `lpVerb` to `openas` and setting `fMask` to `SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST`. However this is not a "one time" thing. In some cases (like for path to an image file on hardeive) it shows a checkbox (but its always checked by default):

[image]

However if I tell it to open a URL, it does not offer this checkbox, it changes:

[image]

Ideally I was hoping for a way, that shows the checkbox, but by default it is unchecked, for all types of paths (url, or file).

Here is my code (js-ctypes):

```
    var sei = ostypes.TYPE.SHELLEXECUTEINFO();
    sei.cbSize = ostypes.TYPE.SHELLEXECUTEINFO.size;
    sei.lpFile = ostypes.TYPE.LPCTSTR.targetType.array()(aPath);
    sei.lpVerb = ostypes.TYPE.LPCTSTR.targetType.array()('openas');
    sei.fMask = ostypes.CONST.SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST;
    sei.nShow = ostypes.CONST.SW_SHOWNORMAL;

    var rez_ShellExecuteEx = ostypes.API('ShellExecuteEx')(sei.address());
```

Comment: The system decides how to do this. Surely you just let the system be in charge.

Comment: Darn there's no way to show the checkbox when doiing open with on links? :( Users are requesting a one time "open with" feature, like when they want to open something in another browser for testing or etc